# Insert vs. emplace_back for appending new element to vector/list if you want an iterator to the newly inserted element

Tags: c++, list, vector, insert, emplace

I understand the general differences between `insert` and `emplace_back` for `std::vector` and `std::list`. Normally, I would just use `emplace_back` any time I want to append an element. For some applications, I need to append the element and have an iterator pointing to that newly appended element.

So typically, I've been doing something like:

```
// for a vector
std::vector<T> v{store some stuff......};
v.emplace_back(new thing);
auto it = v.end() - 1; // now it points to newly inserted element

// for a list
std::list<T> l{store some stuff......};
l.emplace_back(new thing);
auto it = l.end();
--it; // now it points to newly inserted element
```

But I'm wondering if it's better to use:

```
// for a vector
std::vector<T> v{store some stuff......};
auto it = v.insert(v.end(), new thing);

// for a list
std::list<T> l{store some stuff......};
auto it = l.insert(l.end(), new thing);
```

I imagine the difference is negligible if `T` is a POD. But if `T` was some non-POD, which one would be faster if I ultimately want to append and acquire the iterator to the newly appended item? From my understanding, you have to balance the pros of using `emplace`, which constructs an in-place object without copies unlike `insert`, vs. the pros of using `insert`, which really is just giving me an iterator directly seemingly no other benefits. To me, it seems it would be faster to use `emplace` as the extra step of incrementing an iterator is much less expensive than creating a copy of the object?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Just fixed it (regarding your first comment). Re second comment: Yes, I understand it returns a reference, but I specifically need the iterator.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sorry, that was another typo. It should've been `insert`.

Comment: "which one would be faster" seems like a question that can be trivially answered by timing both approaches, by yourself. This will get you a far more accurate answer, with your actual, concrete classes, and your application; as opposed to someone on stackoverflow.com merely guessing which one is faster for some hypothetical class and application.

Comment: I don't understand the last part. `emplace()` returns an iterator as `insert()` does, so why not use `auto it = l.emplace(l.end(), new thing);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no clue about any impact on performances (although I cannot imagine any difference) but if you want to append a new element and obtain a reference on it, you can write

```
auto &r=v.emplace_back(a, b, c);
```

if you prefer to obtain an iterator on it, you can write

```
auto it=v.emplace(cend(v), a, b, c);
```

As far as I can see in the documentation, the only difference is the return type.

- [std::vector::emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace)
- [std::vector::emplace_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)

Comment: Wow I had no idea that there was a difference between `emplace` and `emplace_back` for the `vector` and `list` containers. I literally thought they added `emplace` (as a function that does exactly the same thing as `emplace_back`) for uniform naming convention purposes since other containers like stack, queue, etc... don't have `emplace_back`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is negligible in terms of using insert vs emblace_back. Lists will always be quicker with inserting new elements due to implementation details, since insertion only involves changing a few pointers instead of occasionally reallocating and copying an entirely new dynamic array. I personally would go with emplace_back() and then declaring an iterator on the next line solely because it's a bit easier to read and understand, which could save you some time in the event that something involving this code were to break.